# :hover on a div with a border radius

Tags: html, css, border

I'm having an issue with hovering and a div with a border radius.

When a div has images inside it and a border radius, the "hitbox" for it is incorrect. Hovering over any of the corners of the div (where the corners would be if it didn't have a border radius) causes the hover style to show. I would expect the style to only show when the mouse is actually within the circle.

If there is nothing in the div, the div's "hitbox" is correct, however it surpasses the border when there are elements within it.

I could a background image in the div, however I'd prefer not to for accessibility reasons.

```css
#test-wrapper {
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: 4px dashed #999;
  display: inline-block;
}

#switcher {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#switcher,
#switcher .first,
#switcher .second {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#switcher .first,
#switcher .second {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#switcher:hover .first {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <!-- This is used to show the "hitbox" for the switcher and has no effect on the switcher itself -->
<div id="test-wrapper">
  <div id="switcher">
    <!-- Shown on hover -->
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=30&txt=Second&w=100&h=100&txttrack=0" class="second">
    
    <!-- Always shown -->
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=30&txt=First&w=100&h=100&txttrack=0" class="first">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess the only reason is because HTML is block DOM structure, i guess no **just CSS** easy solution for that.

Comment: I just find it strange that it works fine with nothing in the div. Even applying a border radius to the elements inside the div does nothing, although I guess that's because even though the elements are circular, the div doesn't know that and still uses it's box shape.

Comment: Yes, So if you want you would need SVG. Also you can use HTML `<map>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border-radius and :hover state area issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612439/border-radius-and-hover-state-area-issue)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem here is that child elements do not inherit the `border-radius` of their parents. There are 2 ways to achieve what you want: you can either set the `border-radius` of the child element(s) to match or be greater than the parent element's radius or set the `overflow` property of the parent element to `hidden`.

Here's a quick Snippet illustrating the problem and both solutions:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;color:#fff;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;}
div{
    background:#000;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:150px;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:150px;
}
p{
    background:rgba(255,0,0,.25);
}
div:nth-of-type(2)>p{
    border-radius:50%;
}
div:nth-of-type(3){
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Square hit area</p></div><div><p>Round hit area 1</p></div><div><p>Round hit area 2</p></div>
```

---

If the child elements are images then you'll need the added trick of using an image map to crop their hit areas (Credit: [Border-radius and :hover state area issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612439/)), like so:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;color:#fff;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;}
div{
    background:#000;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:calc(33% - 20px);
    max-width:600px;
}
img{
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}
div:nth-of-type(2)>img{
    border-radius:50%;
}
div:nth-of-type(3){
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div><img alt="" height="600" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/3/" width="600"></div><div><img alt="" height="600" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/3/" width="600" usemap="circle"></div><div><img alt="" height="600" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/3/" width="600" usemap="circle"></div>
<map name="circle"><area shape="circle" coords="0,100%,100%,100%"></map>
```

Comment: Interesting. I actually tried applying both these settings to the snippet in question and neither worked.

Comment: Yes, if you'e using images for the child elements, it requires some extra trickery, which I've now updated my answer with.

Comment: I knew about the overflow trick but I forgot it must be applied to the parent element... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seemed to find a way around it, if the parent element has `overflow` hidden and you just the image `z-index` to -1 or something lower than the parent it also works.
Don't know why though