# Click triggers when clicked outside the div that have border radius

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have the following code to implement a toggle button. The problem with this is if I click on left top or left bottom corners outside the toggle button (still inside the bounding rectangle) , the click or check action is getting triggered as if it is a rectangle. Strangely this only happens in the left side not on the right side.

How can this be stopped?

( *To recreate the problem click on left-top or left-bottom corner of the toggle switch* )

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 34px;
}
.switch input {
  display: none;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2ECC71;
}
input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(25px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(25px);
  transform: translateX(25px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
}
.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div id="utm-parameters-control" class="slider round accordion-control"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: It's because of this line `<label class="switch"></label>`

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373735/-/33373986) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may remove the **width** and **height** from label with `class="switch"`. That should fix the issue:

```
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    /* width: 40px; */
    /* height: 34px; */
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove height and width for the `label` and there you go!

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.switch input {
  display: none;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2ECC71;
}
input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(25px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(25px);
  transform: translateX(25px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
}
.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div id="utm-parameters-control" class="slider round accordion-control"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give your `label` element a `background-color`, as in the below Snippet, you will see the true "hit area".

```css
.switch {
  background:red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 34px;
}
.switch input {
  display: none;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2ECC71;
}
input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(25px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(25px);
  transform: translateX(25px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
}
.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div id="utm-parameters-control" class="slider round accordion-control"></div>
</label>
```

This illustrates a couple of issues:

1. Your `label` is taller than its children,
2. It is also narrower than its children,
3. Its `border-radius` does not match that of its children, as it doesn't have one.

To solve these problems, you'll need to make a few changes to your CSS, as per the following Snippet (I've kept the `background-color` on the `label` for visualisation purposes):

```css
.switch {
  background:red;
  border-radius:25px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
}
.switch input {
  display: none;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2ECC71;
}
input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(25px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(25px);
  transform: translateX(25px);
}
/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
}
.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div id="utm-parameters-control" class="slider round accordion-control"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the image below that .switch class width is not wide enough on the right side.

[screenshot of swift boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4qrH.png)

If you match .slider.round width to .switch width that should work. I also adjusted the height of .switch class so that it's boundary does not exceed.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
}
```