# Hover event on hidden part of the div

Tags: html, css

I have the following sample html with css.
My probem is, when I move the mouse over the top coners of the parent html element, the hover role become active. But it should not be,  because it is a hidden part of the parent.
It is working correctly in firefox, but not in chrome, opera, ie or edge.

Any suggestions?

It is a browser related bug or it is working as intended?

If I remove the position properties from the css, then it is working properly, but is not an option.

```css
.perent{
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.child{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
}

.child:HOVER{
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="perent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:hover on a div with a border radius](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373735/hover-on-a-div-with-a-border-radius)

Comment: It does not solve my problem, my child element can not be rounded and my parent overflow is already hidden

Comment: Why can your child element not be rounded? Why can't you not position it absolutely? In order to answer your question, we must know what restrictions you have, otherwise we'd just be taking stabs in the dark. My solution would be to use clip-path, but what good would that do if you'd just say you can't use clip-path.

Comment: I created a circle menu. My menu items are skewed dives, rotated over the center of the parent circle. I do not want to calculate that arc, which is fit in the parent circle border. If I use absolute position the problem still appears.
https://ibb.co/iQY4i5

Answer (score 1):

For a completely round cut, use this:

Add this:

```
.perent {
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50.0% at 50% 50%);
    clip-path: circle(50.0% at 50% 50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is solve my problem in chrome, but the unfortunately the clip-path not supported in ie.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not sure if it is a browser bug or not, but I can suggest using svg

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 100vh;
}

.child:hover {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
      <clipPath id="clipPath">
        <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50"/>
      </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect class="child" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" fill= "blue" clip-path="url(#clipPath)"/>
  <rect x="0" y="40" width="100" height="60" fill="red" clip-path="url(#clipPath)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: H, thx for your suggestion.
I have tried to integrate your solution to my project, using foreignObject to wrap my html tags, but unfortunately the ie not supports it.

Comment: Did you try inline?