# Overflow hidden not working for hover

Tags: css

I have an issue wherein I am using a div with 50% border radius and overflow hidden property. In this div, There is another div with hover event. The hover event is called even when the cursor is outside the circular div.

CODE:

```css
.check {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pad {
  padding: 2%;
}

.bl {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3.5%;
  line-height: 8;
}

.gr {
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.out {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .gr {
    font-size: 6vh;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .gr {
    font-size: 4vh;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 399px) {
  .gr {
    font-size: 3vh;
  }
}

.out {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.out:hover {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pad">
    <div class="check">
      <div class="out">
        <div class="gr">Technology</div>
        <div class="bl">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Start Quiz</button>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Read Post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pad">
    <div class="check">
      <div class="out">
        <div class="gr">General Knowldege</div>
        <div class="bl">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Start Quiz</button>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Read Post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pad">
    <div class="check">
      <div class="out">
        <div class="gr">Sports</div>
        <div class="bl">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Start Quiz</button>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Read Post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to call hover event inside the circular div only

Comment: If you open the inspector you'll notice that there is not a div really rounded. The div is still a square because making the border rounded doesn't mean that the div is rounded. You need JS to do stuff like that or using area shapes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:hover on a div with a border radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373735/hover-on-a-div-with-a-border-radius)

Comment: @Osakr on the inspect the div will always be rectangular and never rounded even if you apply border-radius or something else

Comment: @Gezzasa you may notice that the solution in that duplicate is already implemented here

Comment: @Osakr Wil it not always show rectangular!?

Comment: @Gezzasa Overflow hidden I had already used but it did not help

Comment: Rectangular or squared depending on the height and width but a div will never be rounded.

Comment: @Pete at least include all his code from the JSFiddle when editing ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif I edited the original question so code was in a snippet rather than just plain text, I am not editing to pull code in from elsewhere - just to make the question in a better format.  If OP wants all code in from fiddle, then that is up to them, it's better than it was so I don't see why you would undo that

Comment: @Pete he shared a partial code to avoid sharing all the code .. so creating a snippet should include all the code. You can clearly see the *huge* difference between the snippet you created and his working fiddle.

Comment: @TemaniAfif In that case then, you should vote to close as off topic as not all the code necessary to reproduce the problem is in the question - I didn't even look at the fiddle so how am I to know that it's vastly different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the `position:relative` you defined, they are creating the issue:

```css
.check {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pad {
  padding: 2%;
}

.bl {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3.5%;
  line-height: 8;
}

.gr {
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.out {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .gr {
    font-size: 6vh;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .gr {
    font-size: 4vh;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 399px) {
  .gr {
    font-size: 3vh;
  }
}

.out {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.out:hover {
  margin-left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pad">
    <div class="check">
      <div class="out">
        <div class="gr">Technology</div>
        <div class="bl">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Start Quiz</button>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Read Post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pad">
    <div class="check">
      <div class="out">
        <div class="gr">General Knowldege</div>
        <div class="bl">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Start Quiz</button>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Read Post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pad">
    <div class="check">
      <div class="out">
        <div class="gr">Sports</div>
        <div class="bl">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Start Quiz</button>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Read Post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```